# "a tall price" vs "a high price"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

One of the meanings of "*tall*" from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tall):

> large in amount or degree; considerable: *a tall price*

As I understood from this definition, "*tall*" in "*a tall price*" means "*high*". Is it so? Is there any difference between "*tall*" and "*high*" when we talk about prices? Thanks!

Comment: Also relevant on ELL: [What is the difference between "tall and high?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29569/what-is-the-difference-between-tall-and-high)

Comment: We *don't* talk about "tall prices".

Comment: Weather Vane, your links don't answer my question because "high" and "tall" are discussed there in terms of the physical distance between two points, and in my example these words are used figuratively.

Comment: Perhaps a dictionary will answer the question: For [tall](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tall): *Of great or more than average height, especially (with reference to an object) relative to width*. For [high](https://www.lexico.com/definition/high): *Great, or greater than normal, in quantity, size, or intensity*. We don't normally say "a tall price" despite your own reference's example.

Comment: ...the use of "tall" in regard to things other than physical objects usually indicates some extreme. A tall story is hard to believe. A tall order is difficult to carry out. A tall price is hard to justify, whereas a high price is more of a factual statement.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'd say that "tall" isn't used when referring to prices because physically _tall_ things start at ground level and continue to a great height (eg tall people, tall trees) but something which is "high" can be disconnected from the ground (high clouds, high-flying aircraft). When we move into metaphoric uses a similar distinction arises, a "tall story" has its beginning in the mundane and becomes more fanciful but a "high" musical note exists at its elevated pitch without the necessity of starting at a low pitch (a bit like a high cloud). High prices are like like clouds as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, this isn't a very well-phrased definition for this meaning.

The meaning of the word *tall* in some instances shades towards *extreme* or *unbelievable*, as in *a tall order* or *a tall tale*. This is one of those instances.

Whereas *a high price* doesn't really convey any judgment on whether you think the price is excessive, *a tall price* gives the impression that you think the price is way too much.

From the OED:

> Large in amount, big. *slang* (originally U.S.). ***tall order***, something expected to be hard to achieve or fulfill.
> 1902: America is the land of ‘tall’ things, and this is certainly a ‘tall’ drink for twenty-five persons.
> 1946: Tall scoring by Indians at Lords.

Note that the *OED* says that this meaning is slang, and my personal impression is that, except for the fixed phrases *tall tale* or *tall order*, it's outdated slang (although I wouldn't be surprised if it was still used in some regions of the U.S.). I would advise against using it.

Answer (score 1):

*Tall* is the word we use for measuring the vertical height of humans

- *He's not tall enough for the part.*

and also metaphorically the vertical height of long upright things (which resemble humans in being long and upright)

- *Sequoias  are the tallest tree in North America.*
- *The Empire State Building was once the tallest in Manhattan.*

  (Mountains are edge cases -- *tall mountains* seems less likely than *high mountains*,
  though I haven't checked Google.)

*High*, on the other hand, is the general term, without any inference about the vertical-to-horizontal ratio of the thing described. It figures prominently in metaphors involving vertical scales, like *high prices, high red count, high scores, high efficiency*. These don't involve actual images of the scale, since a vertical list of numbers doesn't require much imaging.

But *tall* does require an image, and therefore it's only suitable for special metaphors,
like *tall, dark, and handsome* or *tall tale*.

Comment: We also talk of buildings being 20 and 30 storeys high. There happens to be a British TV sitcom called "15 storeys high".  Why it's "storeys" and not "floors" stumps me.